# iOS open app when file is tapped in `Files` app

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument, uti

Some iOS apps with custom file types get launched automatically when a file of that type is tapped (for example, Pages gets launched if a pages file is tapped in the Files app). How can an iOS app which is the owner of a UTI get the same behavior? (The UTI in particular conforms to `com.apple.package`)

I'm using the sample BeerTracking app from https://www.raywenderlich.com/133825/uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial . When a file exported from the app is tapped in the Files app / Mail / Notes, an empty quicklook preview UI appears and only then is the user able to open the file in app by tapping share.

Comment: Tapping on any file from the Files/Mail seems to open a quicklook preview UI for me, Pages documents included.  I'm using the iOS 12 Beta and I have Pages installed.

Comment: @WolfLink on my iOS 11 Device it opens directly the Pages App. But another problem I see is: what app should open a specific document type if multiple apps can open that type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the info.plist add the key "Supports opening documents in place" of type BOOLEAN and set it to TRUE.

You can than check with

```
BOOL openInPlace = [options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsOpenInPlaceKey] boolValue];
```

in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
```

if the provided url is a file that should be opened in place (most likely from the files app).

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to enable **File Sharing**. By add this 2 keys value **YES** in your **Info.plist** file

- 1. UIFileSharingEnabled
  2. LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace

** You can do more stuff by using **UIDocumentInteractionController**
link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller

- To open a file type from iOS files app to your app, you need to have the cloud share functionality in your app so your app can share files into iCloud in a folder named by you app.
- Then you can share any files to iCloud drive and they will show up in the iOS default files app.
- When you tap any files from there (example - image, pdf, video) they will open in your app.

  **UIFileSharingEnabled** will do the work from you.